# How to discard uninstalled applications from ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, uninstall, matlab

I was installing matlab some days before and I have left uninstalled and turned my terminal off. Now, if I want to install new application through terminal in my ubuntu 18.04, it shows error that previous application installation pending. I haven't remember the website now from which website I was installing the matlab. I've searched the net for such information and found different command lines, like these ones:

```
sudo apt-get purge [package]
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

but I don't know the exact package name. it is showing a new pop-up screen with the message "MATLAB interface configuration" The matlab interface need to know where MATLAB is installed on my system. But I have seen my computer and I didn't find matlab in my system.

Comment: Does `sudo apt install -f` fix anything?

Comment: no, it is still showing the same error. thank you for your prompt reply

Answer (score -1):

If you don't know the exact name of the package try the following from tty:

```
history 100 | grep matlab
```

The above will show you which command you used to install matlab, if it was installed through the terminal. 
To see every package installed on your system containing "matlab", run:

```
sudo apt list --installed | grep matlab
```

From there, you should be able to completely remove the package using dpkg:

```
sudo dpkg -P "package-name".
```

For the future, it is highly recommended to only install applications via the apt-cache repository. If you cannot find the package in the apt-cache repository, add the ppa to /etc/apt/sources.list, then run an update.

Comment: by typing command sudo history 100 | grep matlab , it is showing sudo: history: command not found

Comment: Have you tried apt list --installed | grep matlab?

Comment: yeah. Now these messages on the screen.   dynare-matlab/artful,artful, now 4.5.1-1build1 all [installed]

Comment: dynare-matlab/artful,artful,now 4.5.1-1build1 all [installed]
libpdl-io-matlab-perl/artful,now 0.005-2build2 amd64 [installed]
matlab-gdf/artful,artful,now 0.1.2-2.0build7 all [installed]
matlab-support/artful,artful,now 0.0.21 all [installed]
matlab-support-dev/artful,artful,now 0.0.21 all [installed]
matlab2tikz/artful,artful,now 1.1.0-1ubuntu1 all [installed]

Comment: These are the packages you need to remove either one by one or via script.  Use the dpkg example listed above.

Comment: the same error "sudo: dpkg-P: command not found "

Comment: If dpkg isn't working to add/remove programs then you would have to use the apt utility to manually add or remove programs.  "Sudo apt-get purge" or "Sudo apt-get remove package-name"

Comment: sudo dpkg -p dynare-matlab

Comment: Did using dpkg work to solve the problem?

Comment: while removing it goes again into the same pop-up "MATLAB interface configuration"

Comment: As long as the processes within the terminal are still running, everything is fine.

Comment: no, I was using the command sudo apt-get purge dynare-matlab and it was working and has gone again into the same pop-up "MATLAB interface configuartion"

Comment: i don't know if it is running or not, I can only see the screen in the terminal by the pop-up screen hvaing the same message

Comment: Okay,  to make things easier.  Log into a tty session and delete matlab from there.   Are you familiar with tty login?

Comment: no, sir. I don't know

Comment: I'm not sure if MATLAB had been installed in my computer perfectly, i have installed only above mentioned packages.

Comment: I know, it seems like a broken install.

Comment: I'll have step by step directions for you in about 2 minutes.

Comment: okay, logout of your current session.  Once logged out, you will be viewing the normal login screen.   Press ctrl + alt+f1.  This will open up a virtual terminal.  Login with your user name and password.  From there repeat what you were doing above:  sudo apt list --installed | grep matlab.  You should be able to remove these packages using either  dpkg or apt.  Afterwards run an update and that should fix your problem.

Comment: logout from which session.? should I restart the computer? because to open the terminal I didn't login with my ID password.

Comment: restarting is okay.  Be sure to log in to tty by following the directions above.

Comment: Thank you so much. BY Typing sudo apt list --installed | grep matlab there is no previous packages showing installed on this computer related to matlab. Thank you once again

Comment: So did it work for you?

Comment: how to close the answer. i didn't find that

Comment: You can't run `sudo history` because `history` is a shell builtin. And you don't want to anyway, because the command you are looking for was run by your regular user, so you want `history | grep matlab`. Commands you run with `sudo` are stored in your history, not root's.

Comment: @terdon [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it.  The site moderators will catch it.